# Purging/Deleting Data and Reclaiming Space - Oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I am using Oracle DB as Database. One of the table size (say, EMPLOYEE_DETAILS) is 1.6TB. Every week we will be running some jobs, which will consume 300 - 350GB of Storage.

Accordingly i will delete some older data. So that, i will claim the space.

Currently i am following the below process.

```
1. Delete specific data from table, EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.
2. Currently EMPLOYEE_DETAILS table is in TABLESPACE_1.
3. ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS MOVE TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_2.
4. ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS MOVE TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_1.
```

By doing the above steps, which ever data i deleted, i can able to reclaim the free space.

But is this the correct way.? or any other process is there, without moving the table.?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this operation? If this job runs every week, why not just let it reuse the same freed space within the table? You're effectively moving 3.2TB of data, with all the disk i/o and transaction logs that go with it, to reclaim 300GB of space that you're going to almost immediately re-use. Why?

Comment: But, 300-350 GB may not be accurate. There are chances it might consume more. In that case, after deleting the data, how can i find, how much free space available.? Is that possible to get the unclaimed free space size.?

Comment: There's no view that would show you the number of unused blocks within a table - only at the tablespace level. For this reason, most DBAs wouldn't worry a lot about trying to reclaim the space in question unless there was a compelling reason to do so. Depending on how the table is used for example, too many open blocks *may* affect query performance. In your case, since you're constantly reusing the space anyway, there's probably (IMHO) very little point in going through online table redefinition on such a regular basis. I certainly wouldn't do it without a compelling, specific *reason*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do it in this way:

```
LOCK  TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS IN EXCLUSIVE MODE; /* lock the table while you perform the shrinking */
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT; /* enable row movement in order to shrink */
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS SHRINK SPACE COMPACT; /* shrink the table once you've performed the cleaning with the COMPACT option so that it keeps the watermark of it's size, this will cause less overhead when repopulating the table again */
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS DISABLE ROW MOVEMENT; /* disable the row movement again */
```